# in Firestore , how to get documents not seen by the uers before

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

There might be similar questions posted, but not quite what I'm looking for

In FireStore database , I have a list of questions .
My app is supposed to get 30 new random questions each exam ... that the user haven't solved before.

I managed the randomness of the results but I'm still looking for the best way to get new questions for the user ..

So far I guess the best solution is to make a Room Database with an extra field ...Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

Each user could have a document with a field. This field could be an array of strings, and each string is the number of the question the user has already answered.

This way, for each user, you can filter out questions based on ids.